# Family app sharing doesn't share already paid apps

Tags: applications, family-sharing

My brother can't get the app, it says he has to pay. He is in my family on apple, and I already paid for these games, but it still says the price for him to pay. I set that purchases and subscriptions are both shared (this app is a purchase, not a subscription, but this is irrelevant). The app in question is Monument Valley 2.

Why doesn't it show as purchased/free download for my brother?

ps.

It just came to my mind that, maybe the purchases are only shared in sense that a certain payment method is "shared". In my opinion, nothing is shared here, and in this case, only the card would be charged multiple times for each family member. If this is the case (if the "sharing" applies only to the sharing of a mean of payment, between family members), then this my question is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

First, please see apple’s webpage on the topic.

[Apple Family Sharing](https://www.apple.com/family-sharing/)

Make sure again through the iOS App Store that your brother’s App Store account.

Make sure that you’re using the Family Sharing to the right account and that it is being used for his App Store downloads. **Accounts can different for icloud, AppStore, etc.**

Make sure a shared payment method is setup for for your family sharing or else it will not work.

Make sure that you’re sharing the Apple Arcade service. The game in question is an Apple Arcade game as well as a payed game.